# Add option and selection to FAST dropdown from Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

We are using vscode webview ui toolkit in Blazor and are having issues using "FAST" select/dropdown/whatever from Blazor. The problem arises when we try to add options to a previously rendered dropdown and at the same time setting the selection (current-value). I guess the issue is related to the order FAST code runs when attributes are updated by Blazor JS when Blazor applies the "diff" coming from server socket. Here is a small repro of the issue. At load clicking the button doesn't work, select something manually from dropdown and then clicking the button will work ...

Example project showing the issue:
https://github.com/maloo/DropdownRepro/blob/master/Pages/Index.razor